# Tyk Plugin Python

Tags: python, gateway, tyk

I would like to use my own Auth service on every request. I found that by creating plugin is the best way to do it. I am just curious, How can I return an error directly after pre function ?

For example:

1. User access api
2. Plugin check the token that sent along with the api request
3. if it is false, then return error directly to user as Error HTTP 401 without 
   processing into the proxy url.

**UPDATE**

I got this error when using custom auth plugin:

```
{ "error": "Session state is missing or unset! Please make sure that auth headers are properly applied."}
```

And this is how I got there:

https://community.tyk.io/t/create-python-plugin/1369/6

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Information on how to write custom middleware in order to achieve this goal can be found in the official [documentation](https://tyk.io/tyk-documentation/customise-tyk/plugins/rich-plugins/python/). Tyk v2.3 currently supports plugins written in Python 3 as well as LuaJIT, ES5 and gRPC-compatible languages (e.g., Ruby, Java, .NET, &c.).

Further details regarding error templates can be found [here](https://tyk.io/tyk-documentation/customise-tyk/error-templates/), if needed.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting error by using their repo example. {
  "error": "Session state is missing or unset! Please make sure that auth headers are properly applied."
}

Answer (score 0):

The Session object does not exist in all the possible hooks, like the Pre Hook.